# clickhouse external dictionary loading error

Tags: clickhouse

I plan to upgrade clickhouse cluster.From v19.14.6. to v21.3.10.But when I load a  mysql external dictionary on v21.3.10,I got an error:

```
Query:
SYSTEM RELOAD DICTIONARY dim_subject_movie


Received exception from server:
Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Exception: Connections to all replicas failed: frodo@mysql1:3306 as user test, frodo@mysql1:3306 as user test (version 21.3.10.1 (official build))
```

The configuration are as follows

```
  <dictionary>
  <name>dim_subject_movie</name>
  <source>
    <mysql>
      <port>3306</port>
      <user>test</user>
      <password>test1</password>
      <replica>
        <host>mysql1</host>
        <priority>1</priority>
      </replica>
      <db>frodo</db>
      <table>subject_movie_collection</table>
      <where>date=subdate(current_date, 1)</where>
     </mysql>
  </source>
  <lifetime>
    <min>300</min>
    <max>360</max>
  </lifetime>
  <layout><hashed /></layout>
  <structure>
    <id>
      <name>movie_id</name>
    </id>
    <attribute>
      <name>movie_title</name>
      <type>String</type>
      <null_value></null_value>
    </attribute>
  </structure>
  </dictionary>
```

Somebody who ever encountered the same problem?Thankx！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason that because of the dic source (mysql 5.1) is too old to be  compatible with the high version clickhouse. Finally I change clickhouse's version back to 19.14.6.